Stability of atomic/ionic quantum states in relation to the full octet rule
We have started our Chemistry Unit and the very first statement the teacher says is that
"All Atoms want to be stable. They achieve this by having a full valence shell, which they achieve by forming bonds"
Now I understand this, but what is stability?
If stability means for an atom to use or contain the least energy would make ionic bonds correct because it takes energy to seperate opposite ions, hence "letting" opposite ions bond would make them stable, creating an Ionic Bond. A simple analogy is magnets.
However, the part I don't understand is the electron configuration. How is having a full outer shell RELATED to being stable. In fact, having a full outer shell for most atoms should make them unstable because they ionize, hence requiring the opposite ion to stablize. So what is the connection between STABILITY, IONS and HAVING A FULL OUTER SHELL?  Having a full outer shell make the valence electrons repel each other more in some case like when Cl accepts an e-. Plus, all neutral atoms have the same number of protons and electrons, so what more do they really want?

Chemistry is an experimental science. We observe certain compounds, and then we try to model which form and which don’t. The models are always just an approximation of reality, especially the simpler ones you start out with at the beginning.

There is the conflict between the very generally formulated question title and very specific scenario of the question body. // Stability means thermodynamic or kinetic resistance to a spontaneous physical or chemical change, alone, or within the given environment. // It is not clear what other independent resources you have consulted before asking.


All atoms want to be stable. They achieve this by having a full
valence shell, which they achieve by forming bonds.

There are several philosophical and factual problems with this notion. First is the anthropomorphization of non-living objects, which means assigning attributes of choices/thinking/willingness or other human traits to atoms. Atoms do not know or have a personal desire to achieve stability or any sort. The objects, which we call atoms, are subject to the discovered and undiscovered laws of nature. Humans have observed that most objects achieve a state where their calculated energy is a minimum. For example, a long chain tied fixed at both ends with nails hangs downward in such a way that its energy is minimum at equilibrium (like a U shape). We should not say that the chain personally wanted this state. Chain has no choice or thought process but to acquire this shape in a gravitational field. It is the law of nature that makes the chain hang this way.
Now, the next troublesome word is stable. This is one of the most misused words especially in South Asian school and college books of chemistry. Stable itself has no meaning whatsoever in chemistry. We need a reference point when we label something as stable. Ask the question: Stable with respect to what? An atom is stable can mean the following:

It will not change its total energy for an indefinite period due to the properties of charges.
It will not disintegrate into pieces (like radioactive decay, fission, fusion)-nuclear stability
It will not react with anything - chemical stability

You can feel the ambiguity associated with the word stability. In the first part of your query, you are thinking about energy minimization. In the second part the term stability is being used to indicate reactivity.

The part I don't understand is the electron configuration. How is having a full
outer shell related to being stable. In fact, having a full outer
shell for most atoms should make them unstable because they ionize,
hence requiring the opposite ion to stablize. So what is the
connection between STABILITY, IONS and HAVING A FULL OUTER SHELL?

Now we talk about stability with reference to chemical reactivity from a historical point of view. Chemists knew for a long time that noble gases do not react or combine with anything else. The single atoms of those gases are in their "optimum"  energy state. When the electrons were discovered and more was known about the atomic structure by Bohr's theory and others, chemists started to think about the arrangement of electrons in elements as being arranged in shells and later in orbitals. This led to the notion that any atom which acquires the electronic configuration like the noble gas must be "stable" i.e., it will not react further and behave like a noble gas. Just think of sodium.
Its Z= 11, 1s$^2$ 2s$^2$ 2p$^6$ 3s$^1$
Sodium is a highly reactive metal (unstable in air/water etc.), how can it become chemically stable? By acquiring a configuration similar to a noble gas. It is not thinking or choosing. If Na loses an electron, then it becomes Na$^+$ with 1s$^2$ 2s$^2$ 2p$^6$. Which other element has an electronic configuration like that? Neon. A highly unreactive stable gas. Thus, sodium atom has become stable by acquiring an electron configuration like a noble gas (with full outer shell in a classic sense).

anthropomorphization of non-living objects - I think many scientists do so consciously, as figures of speech, mainly in context of lectures, without really assigning such attributes to non sentient objects.

Another term misuse is confusing stability with lack of reactivity (F2 is perfectly stable but highly reactive, ferrous ion is stable in water, but reactive in contact with oxidants)   and not distinguishing thermodynamic and kinetic stability.
